# Swapping multiple images when clicked but one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been searching for a few days for a solution to this problem.

What I have/am trying to do is display some categories on my main page. Each category can be "collapsed" onclick. So far the collapse part works fine but not the image swap for the collapsed icon.

The below code I have changes the image and swaps it back, but no matter which one I click they all only change the very first one listed.

The js in head tag:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var q=0;
function swapImage(){
if(q==0){
document.getElementById("tcat_collapse").setAttribute('src','images/collapsecat.gif');
q++;
}
else{
document.getElementById("tcat_collapse").setAttribute('src','images/expandcat.gif');
q--;
}
}
</script>
```

The image tag I'm swapping:

```
while ($query2->fetch()) {
echo "<tbody><tr><td class='category' colspan='5'>";
echo "<a style=\"float: right\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"toggleItem('catcollapse')\">";
echo "<img class='collapsecat' src='images/collapsecat.gif' border='0' onclick='swapImage();' /></a>";
```

I know it has to do with the getElementByID part.

Most of this site is done in PHP, as you can see it's in a while loop so I have several that display at once with this collapse feature. And I know the javascript looks ugly, but as I've said it works but for only 1 ID.

So what can I do to pull off a collapse of each category individually without having to code each one individually? Can I pass a php variable off as the element ID for this script to change accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Works extremely well:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

var namesVec = new Array("collapsecat.gif", "expandcat.gif");
var root ='images/';
function swapImg(ima){
nr = ima.getAttribute('src').split('/');
nr = nr[nr.length-1]

if(nr==namesVec[0]){ima.setAttribute('src',root+namesVec[1]);}
else{ima.setAttribute('src',root+namesVec[0]);}

}
</script>
```

code looks better too :)

```
while ($query2->fetch()) {
    echo "<tbody><tr><td class='tcat' colspan='5'>";
    echo "<a style=\"float: right\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"toggleItem('collapseobj_forumbit_" . $catid . "')\">";
    echo "<img class='tcat_collapse' src='images/collapsecat.gif' border='0' onclick='swapImg(this)' /></a>";
```

Allows swapping of several images individually no matter of ID due to 'swapImg(this)'.